# Get user input to install file

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to be run this file and see

"1 for example_x
2 for example_y
3 for example_z

Enter number for apk to install:"

Then I press 1, 2, or 3 and enter and the script installs the corresponding .apk via adb (Android Debug Bridge).

When I run this now, I get the message "can't find '1' to install".

```
@echo off

set newline=^& echo.

set 1=example_x.apk
set 2=example_y.apk
set 3=example_z.apk

echo 1 for example_x %newline% 2 for example_y% 3 for example_z %newline%

set /p UserInput= Enter number for apk to install: 

adb install %UserInput%

pause
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for your situation the `choice` command is what you are lookign for (use it in everycase possible). Here is what you need to do to your code:

(Also the problem is not with your command, it is when you use `adb install %UserInput%` look at the soloution)

#### Code :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set newline=^& echo.

set 1=example_x.apk
set 2=example_y.apk
set 3=example_z.apk

echo 1 for example_x %newline% 2 for example_y% 3 for example_z %newline%

choice /c 123 /n /m "Enter number for apk to install: "
set UserInput=%errorlevel%

adb install !%UserInput%!

pause
exit
```

#### Explanation of `choice` and `!%UserInput%!` :

Choice:

- `/n` specify's not to display "[1,2,3}" (which you have already done)
- `/c` Specify Opitions
- `/m ""` Text to display

!%UserInput%!:

- `set UserInput=%errorlevel%` where %errorlevel% is the `ouput` of the `choice` command
- `!%UserInput%!` this only works if you `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and means, whatever result you get from `%UserInput%` is then treated as a variable itself. (`!` is treated the same as a `%`)

Hope this helped, to learn more, type the command followed by `/?`

Yours Mona